# Access - create a sub total in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query over a few tables and get a result in the form of:

```
SomeId      Input
1           2
1           5
2           3
2           1
1           2
```

I'd like to be able to sum by Id as a third field, so I would get

```
SomeId      Input       subTotal
1           2           2
1           5           7
2           3           3
2           1           4
1           2           9
```

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple other ideas. Both have their drawbacks though. Both of them involve using a regular query.

**First idea:** Calling a VBA function to keep track of totals.

The drawback is that you have to order your table by SomeID.

Also the running total only resets itself when the function gets a different SomeID even if it's a different query. This means that the value of SomeID on the first record must be different than the last record of the last previous query.

```
SELECT SomeTable.SomeId, SomeTable.SomeInput, MyRunningTotal([SomeID],[SomeInput]) AS SubTotal
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY SomeTable.SomeId;

Function MyRunningTotal(SomeID As Long, SomeInput As Long) As Long
   Static LastSomeID As Long
   Static RunningTotal As Long
   If SomeID <> LastSomeID Then
      RunningTotal = 0
      LastSomeID = SomeID
   End If
   RunningTotal = RunningTotal + SomeInput
   MyRunningTotal = RunningTotal
End Function
```

**Second Idea:** Using DSum. This is basically a query within a query.

The drawback is that for large recordsets it can be very slow. This    is because it has to run a separate query for every record.

Also, you have to add an Auto-increment field (in the sample code below it's ID).

```
SELECT SomeTable.ID, SomeTable.SomeId, SomeTable.SomeInput, 
DSum("SomeInput","SomeTable","[SomeID]=" & [SomeID] & " and [ID]<=" & [ID]) AS SubTotal
FROM SomeTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's certainly possible, but with the problem as stated it cannot be accomplished by using just Access SQL queries. The two issues are:

1. The source data has no sequential key value (so a self-join with a `<=` condition cannot be used)
2. The source data is not sorted by `SomeId` (suggesting that the order may have some other significance), which would further complicate a set-based approach.

Fortunately, the VBA required to do this is not too involved:

```
Sub CreateSubtotals()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim dct As Object  '' Dictionary
Set dct = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  '' New Dictionary
Set cdb = CurrentDb

'' 'dct' will hold the running totals for each 'SomeId'
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT DISTINCT SomeId " & _
        "FROM qryYourOriginalQuery", _
        dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rst.EOF
    dct.Add rst!SomeId.Value, 0
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close

'' create new table to hold results
cdb.Execute _
        "SELECT SomeId, Input, 0 AS subTotal " & _
        "INTO tblYourDataWithSubtotals " & _
        "FROM qryYourOriginalQuery", _
        dbFailOnError

'' fill in the 'subTotal' column
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("tblYourDataWithSubtotals", dbOpenTable)
Do While Not rst.EOF
    dct(rst!SomeId.Value) = dct(rst!SomeId.Value) + rst!Input.Value
    rst.Edit
    rst!subTotal.Value = dct(rst!SomeId.Value)
    rst.Update
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set dct = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```